# Responsiveness and improve performance in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, responsive-design, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I want to implement responsive UI in my iOS application.I mean to that my app never block UI while navigation during web call. it should be cancelled the web call request if user pop from current viewcontroller which already called web request.
Would anyone suggest me best option for it.

I am thinking for NSOperation subclassing with concurrency. My objective is to provide smooth user interface during navigation from one screen to other which consume web call as well as to improve app performance.

I have googled but not getting any proper guidance which can help me to resolved my problem. In addition to that I don’t preferred to use AFNetworking or RestKit API as my existing project has complex structure.In my existing project I have already used NSURLConnection subclass.its deployment target is iOS 6.

Any kind of help or suggestions will be always welcome !

Thanks in Advance.